# Beat phenomenon in sound waves

Tags: acoustics, interference

I read that beat phenomenon is used to test the quality of air in mines. It stated that if sound of same frequency is passed through two pipes, one containing air and another containing gas from the mine, then the frequency coming out of the pipes is different if mine gas is not pure air and hence on interference, beats are produced.

How will the frequency of sound waves coming out of the pipes change? 
I think the velocity and hence the wavelength of sound in the two media should be different, but frequency must be the same because frequency is the property of the source here.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the frequency here is not set by some tone generator, but is determined by the length of pipes and speed of sound, like in an organ.

If the air is blown through two pipes of the same length, but the property of the air is different and causes the difference of sound speed, the resonant frequencies will be different as well and therefore the two waves could produce beats.